# Como ordenar pelo maior número de agrupamentos, excluindo quem não tiver mais de um agrupamento?

Tags: sql

Preciso ordenar meus registros pelo maior número de **AGRUPAMENTOS**, ou seja,  tenho a SQL abaixo e preciso que a coluna **TIPO** que está sendo **agrupada**, seja ordenada do maior agrupamento para o menor, **excluindo** a exibição do **TIPO** que não tem **AGRUPAMENTO**.

```
(SELECT tipo, count(id) as quantidade
FROM imoveis
WHERE cod = '$cliente'
AND negociacao <> '0'
GROUP BY tipo)
ORDER BY quantidade DESC
```

Aguardo ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que o que você procura seja algo como isso:

```
SELECT tipo,
       count(id) AS quantidade
FROM imoveis
WHERE cod = '$cliente'
      AND negociacao <> '0'
GROUP BY tipo
HAVING quantidade > 1
ORDER BY quantidade DESC
```

Como você está agrupando por tipo, basta você contar quantos ids existem naquele grupo tipo e ordenar por ele.

Comment: A utilização da label não é válida? Humm.. estou sem uma ferramenta para testar no momento, mas acredito que a utilização de labels é sim válida.

Comment: é valida sim creio que está seja a resposta que ele queira. +1

Comment: @Rubico De acordo com o que coloquei o que falta é não exibir o TIPO que não tem agrupamento, pois minha intenção é exibir apenas os tipos que tem agrupamentos e excluir os que não tem.

Comment: Não tinha visto o excluido os que não tem, vou alterar a resposta

Comment: @Rubico Não funcionou amigo. O TIPO que não tem agrupamento continua sendo exibido.

Comment: O que você diria por tipo que não tem agrupamento? O tipo que possui 0 imoveis? Teria como mostrar dar um DESC na sua tabela imoveis e postar o resultado?

Comment: @Rubico Exemplo: Como TIPO tenho os valores: 2 , 8, 6, 8, 2 - Apenas exibiriam os agrupamentos 2 e 8. Excluindo a exibição do 6. Entendeu? Uma vez que 6 está só.

Comment: Entendi que você tem 3 valores e quer exibir 2 deles. Mas não entendi o porque, o que faz desses 8 e 2 serem exibidos e o 6 não? Você está me falando que não existe imovel com o tipo 6?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37115/discussion-between-gladison-neuza-perosini-and-rubico).

Answer (score 0):

Adicione a ordenação no `SELECT` entre os parêtensis:

```
select
id,
tipo
from
imoveis
where
cod = '$cliente'
AND negociacao <> '0'
GROUP BY tipo ORDER BY tipo DESC
```